# Calling a asynchronous android mag stripe library from Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Sorry if this isn't explained very well.  I'm working on a xamarin app that our customers use to scan barcodes.   There are front ends for both iOS and Android.  That part works fine, but I'm trying to add code to access a mag stripe reader on certain android devices.  I can detect if i have the correct device in the code.  Unfortunately the mag stripe reader code is asynchronous so in other words it has a listener that waits for a swipe.  I have sample android app that implements the magstripe reader function but I'm unable to integrate into the Xamarin app.
I've tried calling the full app with an intent

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

         var intent = new Intent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, typeof(JanamScanActivity));
         StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

but it doesn't return a result back that I need and I believe it's too slow anyways.  The scanning and mag stripe reading is done in a task that has a do while loop. Currently the scanner code is using a fragment

```
   StartScanning();

  ((MainApplication)Activity.Application).scannerFragment.ResumeAnalysis();
```

Is there a way for me to create an android library with no UI that i can call from Xamarin.  Currently the library code complains when i don't have runOnUIThread because it needs an activity.

```
 private void postMSRStateChange(final EngineState state)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleMSRStateChange(state);
            }
        });
    }


    protected MsrResultCallback mCallback = new MsrResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final int cmd, final int status) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("onResult");
                    // MSR engine is on another thread. When we get the callback, post the
                    // event to our own message queue then handle the event in the main thread.
                    // Not doing so can/will cause application crash.

                    handleSetResult(cmd, status);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Sorry if I made this confusing.

Comment: So it looks like I'm going to turn this into a separate android service to make this more achieveable.  Thanks to anyone that looked at this.

Comment: so I don't know if it means that you solved your issue now? If yes, please share your solution here, and mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Not entirely but I'm going in a different direction now.  So I guess i can answer my question if that's what you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going in a different direction now.  I'm making a separate application that runs in the background.  Thanks to everyone who looked at this.